# Minecraft Debug screen not updating after mod biome update

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

In my mod I update the biome of specific columns.  It seems to work mostly well - the biome changes instantly. Ice Plains turns into Hell and snow golems die and pigmen spawn.  However the F3 Debug screen does not update and the colors of the grass don't change.

Closing and reopening the Minecraft app does refresh both the F3 debug screen and the grass colors correctly, but I feel there should be a way to make it instant.

FWIW - here's the method that makes the change.

```
private static void setBiome (WorldServer world, BlockPos center, int radius, byte biomeID) {
    // First create a list of chunks that include the full radius
    int minX = center.getX() - radius;
    int maxX = center.getX() + radius;
    int minZ = center.getZ() - radius;
    int maxZ = center.getZ() + radius;

    for (int x=(int)Math.floor(minX/16D); x<=(int)Math.floor(maxX/16D); x++) {
        for (int z=(int)Math.floor(minZ/16D); z<=(int)Math.floor(maxZ/16D); z++) {
            byte[] biomeArray = world.getChunkFromChunkCoords(x,z).getBiomeArray();
            //Second crawl through the array comparing each one to the inside of the radius
            for (int i = 0; i < biomeArray.length; i++) {
                int arrX = Math.floorMod(i,16)+16*x;
                int arrZ = (int)Math.floor(i/16)+16*z;
                  if (minX <= arrX && arrX <=maxX && minZ <= arrZ && arrZ <= maxZ) {
                    //Do the biome change
                     world.getChunkFromChunkCoords(x,z).getBiomeArray()[i] = biomeID;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At Draco18s's suggestion, I tryied syncing by doing world.notifyBlockUpdate, but it didn't seem to work.  I also tried world.notify() which resulted in an IllegalMonitorStateException.

Running forgeSrc 2655 for 1.12.2

Comment: I feel like this question belongs on [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: could be. there's a healthy number of [minecraft] questions here too

Comment: @WorldSEnder Eh, not really. And frankly there are more Minecraft questions on SO than GD. Scott: sounds like a client/server sync issue.

Comment: Spent time experimenting with world.notify to force the sync, but I think I might be looking in the wrong place. I updated the question with the full method.

Comment: You might have to send a custom packet to the client to update its cloned biome array. Minecraft assumes that biomes never change.